# Child custody case and allowing another individual to deal directly with the solicitor

Tags: united-kingdom, family-law

We have a family member J. Doe in the UK who is going through a solicitor to deal with an issue related to child custody and visitation. The family is wondering if there is a way that J. Doe can grant another family member the right to deal directly with the solicitor, so they can discuss the case, receive updates, and provide guidance to the solicitor. Essentially, act as a representative for J. Doe, with J. Doe's consent.

We are not experts in the law, and most of the information we find online is related to more drastic measures such as granting someone power of attorney. Is there any case or issue related measure that could be taken to allow other family member to represent J. Doe in this case (not within court, but mainly within the preparatory stages).

Comment: A solicitor has been instructed, so why not ask them?